# Phonegap Build - "PushPlugin" server notification

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

(ios) I am trying to send push notifications from my server. 
Right now I have the plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />  // config.xml
```

and js file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script> // index.html
```

and my code is:

```
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;


    });
```

**I got certificates.**

**But how do you send the request to the server?** In my case I want to check the server every minute and see if there are any news for my user...

Any help would be appreciated

///////////////////

**I FOUND THE ANSWER!!!**

1. user "cron jobs" in your php file on the server to send automatic notifications.
2. follow this tutorial http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to request the server every minute. When your server has news for your user, *send a notification* to the user's device, from the server.

Comment: And how can I make the server to make a request automatically? What if my computer is off and I still want to send a notification?

Comment: That cannot be answered in the comments. Ask a new question explaining how the server knows when there is news for the user and how you are sending the notifications.

Comment: Ok, I found I can user "cron jobs", thanks for you help